# Kendo grid column number formatting

Tags: templates, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, number-formatting

How to set number formatting in kendo column if we bind 2 data values? In my example I have to bind value with unit, so I need a value written with 2 decimals.
My code looks like:

```
{
    field: "Quantity",
    title: "Value ",
    width: "70px",
    type: "number",
    format:"{0:n2}",
    template: "#:Quantity# #:Unit#",
    attributes:{style:"text-align:right;"}
},
```

Without binding it to unit it works great, but with unit I have a problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will format `Quantity` to show as a number with 2 decimals

```
template: '#= kendo.toString(Quantity, "n2")#  #=Unit#'
```

Comment: should I just put it to my column properties? I tried and it doesn't work :/

Comment: I was missing a `#` sign.  Try it again with the above.

Comment: works great, thank You very much, unfortunately I have not enough reputation for marking Your comment as good, but thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Above given answer is fine but you can also achieve the same result by using separate kendo templates for more customization options.

```
template: kendo.template($("#quantity-tmplt").html())
```

Define your template.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="quantity-tmplt">
    <div>#= kendo.toString(Quantity, "n2") #</div>
</script>
```

For more information, read [KendoGrid Column Template](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.template)